# How to create MySQL in SQL script and set max_allowed_packet

Tags: mysql

I got a large SQL script - created by dump in MySQL Workbench - which creates a MySQL database.
In the AWS cloud the script runs perfectly.
But when i connect in MySQL Workbench to a local server and execute the script there, it crashes while inserting data to a large table because the max_allowed_packet is just 1048576 bytes long.
In the AWS cloud it's 4194304 bytes.

Can i change max_allowed_packet in my SQL script just for the one database i want to create?
That's propably very difficult because max_allowed_packet is read only as i have found out meanwhile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can change it in `my.cnf` and restart the server. *HOWEVER* you should not. You didn't specify *how* you're inserting the data - do you use CLI `mysqldump` or `mysql` or `mysqlimport`? Are you using some kind of `.sh` or `.php` or any other language to insert the data? If you have an `.sql` file, you should use CLI tools to import it. However, if it's one-off thing and you just want the data -> `vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`, (no clue where that is on Windows though), change the max_packet_size, import it and voila.

Comment: @N.B. I added more information to my question. First i created with MySQL WorkBench V6.3.10 a dump from a database which is in the AWS cloud. Then i connected in the workbench to a database which is on a local server (with max_allowed_packet = 1048576 bytes) and executed it there.